# How to perform an action on a page of rows loaded via AJAX

Tags: tabulator

I'm trying to act on a page of rows after they are loaded into the table via AJAX from a remote source. In this case, the goal is to select rows based on some application logic.

The comment [here](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2429#issuecomment-542253754) suggests that the `dataLoaded` event should be used for this:

```
When the dataLoaded callback is triggered after data is loaded. You could then use the 
getRows function on the table to get an array of all the rows, iterate over them, check 
if they should be selected then call the select function on the row component.
```

However, the rows appear to be unavailable in this event. This has been [confirmed](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3912#issuecomment-1225266551) as by-design:

```
This is correct behaviour, as the documentation states this is called before the data is 
processed into row components, so there aren't the row components to return
```

I have also tried the `pageLoaded` event, however, the rows are not available in this event either.

What event or callback can I use to iterate through the rows of a page in the table *after* they are loaded/processed?

I have a CodePen as an example of what I'm trying to do [here](https://codepen.io/omfgicbf/pen/QWmPpoz).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was a clue in the author's confirmation of the behaviour of the `dataLoaded` event.

The `dataProcessed` event fires after the rows are created and contains the expected rows for that page.